# Bundle for page is not send css on routing via goto(). Only JS bundle/chunk is shipped. Happens only on prod

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I use svelte kit. I have multiple pages. My structure is like this:

[image]

**Happens only on prod.** If I am on a page, and navigate via `goto('register')` to the other page, the css wont load and wont be shipped.
Only after a full page reload, the styles are there. But if I navigate back via goto() , the styles of the other components/page are gone until I do a full page refresh.

**What it looks like with styles. (including the css call)**
[image]

What it looks like when I route via `goto('register')`:

[image]

As you can see, on the regular routing, no .css bundle for register is sent. Only the js.

What can I do ?

Also my svelte.config.cjs

```js
module.exports = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
        scss: {
            includePaths: ['src/styles/']
        }

    }),
    kit: {
        // By default, `npm run build` will create a standard Node app.
        // You can create optimized builds for different platforms by
        // specifying a different adapter
        adapter: node(),
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        files: {
            hooks: 'src/hooks'
        },
        target: '#svelte',
        vite: {
            ssr: {
                noExternal: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})
            },
        },
        ssr:false,
    }
};
```

Also with or without ssr this issue occures.
On dev it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an older verion (`1.0.0-next.67`) of svelte kit.
**deleted** the node modules and the package-lock.json, ran `npm i` and all of a sudden the prod builds started to work propperly.
Now its verion `1.0.0-next.95`.

**TL:DR**
It was a beta bug that could be resolved by clean installing the newest version of svelte kit.